# AndEngine - unregister and then register all scene's touch areas

Tags: android, andengine, out-of-memory

I'm developing an android app using AndEngine. I have a game scene with draggable objects. When an object is being dragged, I want all other objects to have their touch areas unregistered so they wouldn't interfere, and when the dragging action is done- to re-register all touch areas.

I tried doing this by trying this when the drag starts:

```
        touchAreas = gameScene.getTouchAreas();

    try {
        gameScene.detachChild(towerDragSprite);
        gameScene.detachChild(rangeDragSprite);
        gameScene.unregisterTouchArea(rangeDragSprite);
        for (int i = 0; i < touchAreas.size(); i++)
            gameScene.unregisterTouchArea(touchAreas.get(i));
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    }
```

and this when the drag completes:

```
if (!pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
                .
                .
                .
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < touchAreas.size(); i++)
                        gameScene.registerTouchArea(touchAreas.get(i));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                return true;
            }
```

But I'm getting an OutOfMemory exception when the drag is completed (even when there aren't many touch areas).

I've seen that a scene in AndEngine also has a `scene.unregisterTouchAreas(ITouchAreaMathcer pTouchAreaMatcher)` method, but I have no idea how to get an ITouchAreaMatcher, and couldn't find a solution on the internet.

Anyone knows what to do?

Thanks

Comment: ITouchAreaMatcher is easy to make, just create an anonymous inner class and define what a match is. I used it to unregister everything, so I just let the method return true every time. If you're using Eclipse, just write "new" in the parameter and hit ctrl+space and choose the right interface. Eclipse will fill the syntactic sugar for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked in unregistering all touch areas! But now how can I re-register them? I tried capturing all touch areas in an `ArrayList` using `scene.getTouchAreas()` and then looping `scene.registerTouchArea(touchAreas.get(i))` in a for loop when the drag movement was over, but it didn't do anything. I will continue trying other methods, but is there an easy solution I'm missing?

Comment: I simply go through all the children in a for loop and call mScene.registerTouchArea((ITouchArea) mScene.getChild(i)); While doing this, I check whether the children being registered are those I actually want to register.

Answer (score 1):

Check out either [MultiTouchExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/MultiTouchExample.java) or [TouchDragExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/TouchDragExample.java) in the [AndEngineExamples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/). Both of these do touching and dragging. The multitouch one is multitouch obviously, but also has other entities that are not bothered if you drag the current one over them. Maybe that will help you?

You can try these examples out with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.anddev.andengine.examples), if you didn't know already.

By the way... just for kicks, have you tried

```
 mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

?

Judging by your post I think you're making this way harder than it has to be. What you're trying to do is a common function that should be easy to do with the engine.